# How can I edit HTTP request in OWASP ZAP and send the edited request?

Tags: web-application, appsec, proxy, owasp, zap

I'm aware of setting a breakpoint on a particular request and then when the request is made in the browser, the http request can be modified in ZAP. But is there any way in ZAP, by which an already made request can be edited and sent?

For example:

[image]

Then how can I edit such request and send it through OWASP ZAP?

Comment: When I google the question, I get: https://github.com/owtf/owtf/wiki/Quick-Guide-to-get-started-with-Zest,ZAP-and-Replay

Comment: What you appear to be asking for is to replay a stored request.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try right click, "resend"? Then you get a new window and in the "Request" tab you can change the parameters. Maybe it doesn't work in the "Sites" pane and you need to go to the "history" tab in the bottom.

Comment: It will work in both the "Sites" and "History" tabs, and any other tab that shows requests, like the Active Scan tab.

Comment: By the way, in the latest version (2.80), the "resend" is changed to "Open/Resend with Request Editor"

Answer (score -1):

1- Right click on any request and click on resent
[image]

2- Edit header and body and then click on send
[image]